# Random requests to my ktor http server from internet

Tags: http, security, https, netty

I am developing a server for my Android app, and there are multiple JAR files developed in KTor server which are running on different port numbers and act as servers for different services for my clients.
I am still in development but decided to run the servers for a couple of months just to see how many random internet requests I get, particularly since I have not even released my app or anything on the website.
I have multiple warning messages from my ktor servers, sometimes getting multiple messages per day, sometimes 1 in 3-4 days, and it all varies for different JAR files.
Below are some of the messages printed in my log file as examples:

```
2023-11-19 11:14:25.444 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE Application - Failed to decode request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: text is empty (possibly HTTP/0.9)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:72)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpRequestDecoder.createMessage(HttpRequestDecoder.java:153)
...(many more lines like this)


2023-11-04 20:28:12.452 [eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] TRACE Application - Failed to decode request
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: >??W?.???????? ?? ? 3 9 5 /?,?0 ? ????????????????]?A?W?S?+?/ ? ??????????\?`?V?R?$?( K J?S?W ? ??#?' G @?R?V ? ??
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.<init>(HttpVersion.java:123)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpVersion.valueOf(HttpVersion.java:85)
...


20-11-2023 11:40:31.413 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline - An exceptionCaught() event was fired, and it reached at the tail of the pipeline. It usually means the last handler in the pipeline did not handle the exception.
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
...


18-11-2023 05:49:01.137 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0xbed13849, L:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx - R:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] Failed to select the application-level protocol:
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
    at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
...


18-11-2023 05:48:54.505 [eventLoopGroupProxy-3-1] [WARN ] i.n.h.s.ApplicationProtocolNegotiationHandler - [id: 0xd2257bd3, L:x.x.x.x/x.x.x.x:xxxx ! R:/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxxx] TLS handshake failed:
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0100000000cd00010000414e592d5343502020202020202020204543484f534355202020202020202020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000010000322e3237362e302e373233303031302e332e302e332e362e325500000f4f464649535f44434d544b5f333632
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1225)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1295)
...
```

Any idea whether these are hacking attempts or harmless bots or something I need to handle?

Comment: I would do like most app API developers do: check for a header field with an API key and if the header is not present or does not contains the expected value simply ignore the request.

Comment: @Robert thank you for your suggestion. The problem is that KTor netty is filterring out warnings to log and does not go to the function where the page is called. So I have no way of checking in this case since netty just automatically routes within internal code and never comes back to my code.